# NoSuchMethodError when I use android.widget.RelativeLayout.setBackground

Tags: android, nosuchmethoderror

At android 4.2 my app works fine, but when I try to test it using android 4.0.4 I have this message error:

```
04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.RelativeLayout.setBackground
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at com.myapp.MainActivity.cambiarPagina(MainActivity.java:271)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at com.myapp.MainActivity.cambiarPagina(MainActivity.java:119)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at com.myapp.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:116)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at com.myapp.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3524)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14202)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4499)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
    04-16 15:06:46.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3844):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I use setBackgroud to add some animation, like this code

```
AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
                                 animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d1), 200);
                                 animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dio), 1000);
                                 animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.da1), 200);
 animation.setOneShot(true);
 view.setBackground(animation);
 view.post(new Starter(animation));
```

I have support library added to my project, and I don't know how solve this, any help will be apreciated!

Comment: What is there in MainActivity.java:271 ? What is the type of view in `view.setBackground(animation);' ?

Comment: read the doc, setBackgroundDrawable does not exist before API 16.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That was added in [API 16](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29), try `setBackgroundDrawable()`

Comment: Hi dmon, Thanks for your answer, If I use setBackgroudDrawable() eclipse say it's deprecated

Comment: That's fine, that's because they added the other method. It's interesting that they deprecated the other one given that they are not 100% compatible. Though granted, I did not appreciate how the old method worked :)

Comment: Thanks @dmon ! It works for me! One question, I can detect android api level and only use the deprecated method at previous versions to api 16?

Comment: why is now deprecated

Answer (score 31):

In addition to @dmon answer: you could call the proper method in this way:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {

    layout.setBackground(animation);

} else {

    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it worked for me:

```html
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new ImageLoader().fullPath + "/desiredFilename.png");
Resources res = getResources();
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
   ll.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
else 
   ll.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

this was my problem :

```
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(popupWindow.createDragToOpenListener(imageButton));
```

and I fixed it like this :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    imageButton.setOnTouchListener(popupWindow.createDragToOpenListener(imageButton));
                }
```